# What does each rune on the floor do?

Tags: conclave

In Conclave there are several types of runes, like

- Earth Rune
- Fire Rune
- Air Rune
- Necrotic Rune

What are the positive and negative effects of each rune?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Vitalizing Rune

[image]

- Step into the rune will grant you +2 Strength
  [image]
- While in the rune will grant you being healed by +1
  [image]

---

### Fire Rune

[image]

- Staying in the rune make your opponents in 6 squares receive fire damage. The damage increase as close the target is from the rune. The damage is AoE.
  [image]

---

### Earth Rune

[image]

- Staying in the rune will grant you +2 physical resistance
  [image]

---

### Air Rune

[image]

- Staying in the rune make your opponents in 6 squares receive blunt damage. The damage increase as close the target is from the rune. The damage is AoE.
  [image]
  [image]

---

### Extras

- The quest `Ash and Ember` the choice "Light Rune" will bring you to a room with one rune of each (**Air**, **Fire**, **Earth**)
- Runes can also **miss** an attack. as it shows in the below image. It occurs because the target is immune to that type of damage. (only case that I could get a miss)
  [image]
- Runes work for monsters as it work for us, sometime works in the reverse way like the case of the Necrotic rune.
  [image]

Comment: I'm still editing. be patient please